# Sql Server - Unable to access certificate after creating it

Tags: sql-server, x509certificate

I'm trying to create a login from a certificate. I am able to create the certificate

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [IfxSqlClr-ClrStrictSecurity2-Cert] 
FROM BINARY = 0x30820268308201D5A00...
```

and ...

[image]

However when I try and create a login from it

```
CREATE LOGIN [IfxSqlClr-ClrStrictSecurity2-Login] 
FROM CERTIFICATE [IfxSqlClr-ClrStrictSecurity2-Cert];
```

I get an error

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Cannot find the certificate 'IfxSqlClr-ClrStrictSecurity2-Cert', 
because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I'm struggling to understand what is going on and what additional permissions I may need or whether I'm not creating the certificate correctly. FYI I'm following [this link](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

TIA

Comment: Which database did  you create the certificate in?

Comment: thx .. not in master ...is that the issue? Actually that user doesn't have permissions to create a certificate in master

Comment: @SimonWoods, right, login certs must exist in master. If you need the same cert in the user database, create it there too.

Comment: brilliant … thx to your both

Comment: *"not in master ...is that the issue?"* Yes, have a check of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"CERTIFICATE certname Specifies the name of a certificate to be associated with this login. **This certificate must already occur in the master database.**"*

Comment: @Larnu  Thx very much